# DataTable not displaying info JSF

Tags: jsf, datatable

I'm having trouble with a DataTable.
I have a **SelectOneMenu** component with 3 options. Every option should render a **DataTable** with different information.

My **xhtml** page is working (I tested it with a simple code), but it seems that my **backing bean** is not working as I was expecting. When I run the page throws an error message.

My xhtml looks like

```
<h:form>
        <h:outputLabel for="reporte" value="Tipo de reporte: " />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="reporte"
                         value="#{reportController.type}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione tipo de reporte..." itemValue="null" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{reportController.reportType}" />
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>




        <h:panelGrid id="porSistema"
                     rendered="#{reportController.type == 'Por sistema'}">
            <h:dataTable value="#{reportController.list}" var="item"
                         border="1">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nombre del archivo"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.fileName}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Registros correctos"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.registersOk}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Registros incorrectos"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.registersNok}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Registros procesados"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.registers}"/>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

The bean is

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ReportController {

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    String type;
    String[] reportType = new String[]{"Por sistema",
        "Por programa y componente",
        "Por estatus de pago"};

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (type.equals("Por sistema")) {
            list.add(new ReporteSistema("A", "B", "C", "D"));
        } else if (type.equals("Por programa y componente")) {
            list.add(new ReporteProgramaComponenteA("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"));
        } else if (type.equals("Por estatus de pago")) {
            list.add(new ReporteProgramaComponenteB("K", "L", "M", "N"));
        }
    }

    public String[] getReportType() {
        return reportType;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Object> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

and the stack trace is

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Se ha producido un error al realizar la inyección de recurso en el bean administrado reportController
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getCurrentSelectedValues(MenuRenderer.java:648)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:749)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:844)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at mx.gob.sagarpa.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:117)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mx.gob.sagarpa.beans.ReportController.init(ReportController.java:32)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Look what's in row 32 of ReportController.java

Comment: Yes that NullPointerException is making my page crashes. The line 32 is the `if(type.equals("Something"))` so I suppose that the variable **type** is null, but it is supposed to change when the value of the SelectOneMenu changes... so why is it throwing a NullPointerException ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the purpose of the [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html). This annotation is to be used to specify methods which are to be executed **directly** after bean's construction. This annotation allows you to execute code *after* injection of managed properties specified by [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) and all other dependencies such as [`@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) or [`@EJB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html). Those injected properties and dependencies are namely not available inside the bean's constructor (a fully constructed instance of the bean has to be obtained first before all injections can take place, of course). The `@PostConstruct` of a view scoped bean is not invoked when you send an ajax request on it. It's only invoked when you initially open the page in the browser.

You actually want to invoke that method when the ajax event is fired. You need to change the view and bean as follows in order to get it to work.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="reporte" value="#{reportController.type}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione tipo de reporte..." itemValue="null" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{reportController.reportType}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{reportController.changeType}" render="@form" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

*(note the new `listener` attribute)*

and

```
public void changeType() { // No, do not put @PostConstruct on it!
    if ("Por sistema".equals(type)) {
        list.add(new ReporteSistema("A", "B", "C", "D"));
    } else if ("Por programa y componente".equals(type)) {
        list.add(new ReporteProgramaComponenteA("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"));
    } else if ("Por estatus de pago".equals(type)) {
        list.add(new ReporteProgramaComponenteB("K", "L", "M", "N"));
    }
}
```

Also note that I swapped the both sides of the `equals()` so that you can guarantee that it will never throw NPE. If the `type` happen to be `null`, then it will simply be compared as non-equal. When you actually invoked `equals()` on something which is `null`, you will guaranteed get a NPE (that's what the whole exception stands for! see also [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is obviously stated in the stacktrace. Your `init` method threw a `NullPointerException`. To be precise, your `type` variable was not given any value. You cannot call `equals` function with it.